What would happen to the US economy if the NFL was banned next season?
Would there be inflation? Would parts of American culture change significantly? Which parts?

That depends on what is very specifically meant by banning the NFL. Note that banning a legal person is not really a thing; when the popular press says that such and such legal person is to be banned that's always code for something vastly more subtle. VTC as the question needs to actually explain what is to happen to the NFL.

How is this a world building question? looks like just a just a google question. How much does the NFL contribute to the US economy, hint not much.

I agree, this is not a worldbuilding question.

Hello @aks. Allow me to be more specific about why your question ws closed. (a) While we accept Real World questions, we expect there to be a worldbuilding context. (b) Users are allowed to ask one and only one question per post. (c) We call this type of question a High Concept Question, and they're off-topic because they're always opinion-based, too broad, too vague, and too story-based. I'll give you some insight, though. (1) No, no inflation. (2) For just one season? No aspect of American culture would change.

Also, you can look at the impact that past NFL player strikes have had on the economy - not much.
